# AVSpeechSynthesizer works on simulator but not on device

Tags: objective-c, ios7, avspeechsynthesizer

I've been trying to learn AVSpeechSynthesis. The code works fine in the iOS Simulator (both on iPad and iOS) but the text to speech feature doesn't work at all on my iPad. Here's my code.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



//Load Model
    self.string = @"Hello World";
    self.utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:self.string];
    self.utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
    self.utterance.rate = (float) 0.25;

    //Load UI
    self.textLabel.text = self.string;


}

- (IBAction)startSpeaking:(id)sender {

    self.speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

    if ([self.speechSynthesizer isSpeaking]) {

        [self.speechSynthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryWord];


    } else {

        [self.speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:self.utterance];

    }    
}
```

**UPDATE: AVSpeechSyntheSizer is working but no sound**
So I have a UILabel with the same text as the AVSpeechUtterance on the UI. I implemented AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate so that when I hit startSpeaking: the text label turns the current word red. So I know that AVSpeechSynthesizer must be working because it's making delegate calls but I can't figure out why I can't hear it. The volume is up and no other apps are playing audio.

Comment: Make sure self.speechSynthesizer isn't going out of scope.  It has to exist for the entire duration of the utterance.

Comment: @Daniel Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 13):

Do you have the phone in silent mode? That silences the synthesizer as well.

Comment: Thanks. I checked for that. It's definitely not in silent mode.

Comment: I do notice however sometimes certain videos on facebook or youtube will play with no sound (even though it's not in silent). Not sure if that might be related.

Comment: Switch On the Ringer. Which is placed on top of the Volume button and check.

Comment: @sonu :- I was trying from last half an hour. Thanks dear. It works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

It's not working because of the `Mute` mode of your phone. To turn 'Mute On' in iOS 7, you have to follow the following steps:

- Go to your `Setting` option
- Go to `Accessibility`
- Go to `AssistiveTouch`
- Turn on `AssistiveTouch` option from the switch button
- Then a Moving Assistive icon, will appear on you device screen.
- Touch on it to expand with more options
- From there select `Device` and Touch `Un mute` option.

Now run the project and hope it will work.

**P.S:** (In iOS 8.0 this code wouldn't work, because for an unexpected bug, from iOS8.1 they remove it and it is now working perfectly)
Hope it works. :)

Comment: This did the trick indeed on my iPhone SE! This must be the accepted answer.

Comment: I had the notifications disabled via the soft switch on the control panel.