# Unable to hear any output from Text to Speech

Tags: codenameone

I am creating my own Codenameone application that uses the Text to Speech functionality in IOS 8.  My application uses the same native IOS code as given in the DrSbaitso demo. I can build my application and deploy it to my IPhone successfully, however I am never able to hear any output from the Text to Speech. I have verified that the native interface is getting called, but I cannot hear any sound.  Is there something else that needs to be implemented than just the native interface that will call the IOS text to speech functionality?  Is there perhaps something I need to enable on my IPhone to use the Text to Speech API?  I have listed my native implementation code that I am using.

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface com_testapp_demos_TTSImpl: NSObject {
}

-(void)say:(NSString*)param;
-(BOOL)isSupported;
@end
```

Source:

```
#import "com_testapp_demos_TTSImpl.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation com_testapp_demos_TTSImpl

-(void)say:(NSString*)param{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-GB"];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:param];
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *syn = [[[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init]autorelease];
    utterance.rate = 0;
    utterance.voice = voice;
    [syn speakUtterance:utterance];
    [pool release];
}

-(BOOL)isSupported{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the volume is up and that the device isn't in mute mode.

Notice that in iOS a device may be in mute mode and still play sounds so this is a common mistake!

See [AVSpeechSynthesizer works on simulator but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093434/avspeechsynthesizer-works-on-simulator-but-not-on-device)

Comment: Thank you!  I believe I had my IPhone in silent mode. Sorry for the newbie mistake.

Comment: I made that same mistake too when I started working with iOS media. It's really unclear in iOS when your device is muted as apps such as Skype don't respect that setting... BTW You need to accept questions that are answered correctly.