# Xamarin iOS: Doesn't make any sound using AVSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: ios, xamarin, speech-to-text

I tried to follow the sample code in the Xamarin Documentation about speech to text. The android part work for my android phone but test on the iPhone it didn't make any sound. I added the delegate function "DidStartSpeechUtterance" and it did call the delegate function but no sound from the phone.

```
            var speechSynthesizer = new AVSpeechSynthesizer();

        var speechUtterance = new AVSpeechUtterance(text)
        {
            Rate = AVSpeechUtterance.MaximumSpeechRate / 4,
            Voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.FromLanguage("en-US"),
            Volume = 0.5f,
            PitchMultiplier = 1.0f
        };
        speechSynthesizer.DidStartSpeechUtterance += (sender, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Am I get called");
        };

        speechSynthesizer.SpeakUtterance(speechUtterance);
```

It works on the emulator iPhone SE iOS 10.2, but not the actual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have a direct answer for you sadly, however:

You **could** try if James Montemagno's nuget package works for you:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/TextToSpeechPlugin

This was made to abstract away the implementation so that you can use it from a (Shared) portable class library - it helps you to share even more code as well. I'm curious if that does work for you. If that doesn't work either something else is wrong (outside the speech-synthesizer part)

Comment: This means something else is amiss. Have you tried a 'different' physical iPhone? It might be a setting, it might be volume for speech, it might be forcefully disabled. Did you try setting up the permission for "background audio" ? That might be it. That, or try what people say at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093434/avspeechsynthesizer-works-on-simulator-but-not-on-device - a number of tips there.

Comment: I have tried it on a new empty project. It did work but my working project is not working. Do you know anywhere it can be disabled or can i check whether its been disabled or not.

Comment: I think I found the problem I have set this statement    AVFoundation.AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetCategory(AVFoundation.AVAudioSessionCategory.Record); . I change it to PlayAndRecord to have it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem :

AVFoundation.AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetCategory(‌​AVFoundation.AVAudio‌​SessionCategory.Reco‌​rd); . I change it to PlayAndRecord to have it worked.

Comment: Awesome that you found it!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem I have set this statement AVFoundation.AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetCategory(‌​AVFoundation.AVAudio‌​SessionCategory.Reco‌​rd); . I change it to PlayAndRecord to have it worked